# ImageMagick: Composite images with text image, the outcome image invert the white background to black

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, exec

I really need some help to understand the image channel problem,
I used ImageMagick to gen a **text image** with jpg 300 dpi RGB.

I then merge this image on the top of a **background image**(jpg 300 dpi CMYK 8bits/Channel).

I find the **text image is normal** when open this by default/photoshop, however when I merge to the **background image**, it have become inverting the color tone, black and white.

can anybody tell me what's wrong with the image? 
please help I have tried couple of hours  however still no answer
I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.9-10

This is the command I ran:

```
convert -background white -fill black \
      -font 'Brandon_reg.otf' \
            -pointsize 9 -size 445x -density 300 -gravity center\
            caption:'Why this message become invert the black and white?' \
      msg.jpg"


convert background.jpg msg.jpg \
            -gravity center -composite output.jpg
```

[please see this image](http://i207.photobucket.com/albums/bb84/squall1999/Untitled-1_zpsnlmc9t1l.jpg)

Comment: Maybe update your software before you worry too much... Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 2015-03-10

Comment: I'm running 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't see inverted colors - indeed, there seems to be a version dependency